# How to generate the public key from Polkadot Address from Substrate Side

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I'm generating a Public key from PolkadotJS as follows

```js
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: "sr25519" });
    const account = keyring.addFromUri("//Bob", { name: "Bob default" });
    
    // encoded public key 
    let public_key = keyring.encodeAddress(account.publicKey, 42);
    console.log(public_key);
```

I am adding the type of `public_key` as `"public_key": "Vec<u8>",`

I am reading the public key from Substrate Node as follows

```rust
// pk_raw is a Vec<u8> array 
let pk =  str::from_utf8(pk_raw.as_ref()).unwrap() 
// the above returns `5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty`
```

I need to generate the public key from this value. I tried with the followings

```rust
ed25519::Public::try_from(&*pk_raw).unwrap(); 
// above throws error since the data length is not equals to 32

fn try_from(data: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if data.len() == 32 {
            let mut inner = [0u8; 32];
            inner.copy_from_slice(data);
            Ok(Public(inner))
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to generate the public key using `5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty` from Substrate Rust Side?

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this:

```
use sp_core::crypto::Ss58Codec;

ed25519::Public::from_ss58check("5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty").expect("Valid address")
```

Comment: This throws the following error let e = ed25519::Public::from_ss58check("5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty").
      |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in 
 sp_core::ed25519::Public It cannot find `from_ss58check`

Comment: Have you imported the trait?

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/core/src/ed25519.rs#L150-L157 here it is called as well.